# SQL query error: “right parenthesis missing missing”

Tags: sql, oracle

The problem: Display hospitalid, hname, htype of hospital(s) which has the highest number of doctors associated with them.

The `patient` table:

```
patientid
pname
address
amount
ptype
```

The `hospital` table

```
hospitalid
hname
htype
```

The `doctor` table:

```
doctorid
dname
specialization
hospitalid
status
```

The `billing` table:

```
billingid
patientid
doctorid
fees
billdate
```

So far this is what I have:

```
select * from hospital where hospitalid =
  (select hospitalid from doctor group by hospitalid having count ( doctorid ) =
      (select max ( doctoramt ) from
          (select count (doctorid) as doctoramt from doctor group by hospitalid) as tbltemp));
```

Comment: Could anyone please help me asap

Comment: Tip for future question: please **always** define what database system you're using (as a tag). SQL is just the query language - **not** a database product ....

Comment: Thanks... Using Oracle

Comment: Do not post duplicate questions.

Comment: You ppl don't provide me the answers I'm looking for

Comment: Hence reposting so that someone else helps/

Comment: @ShanthaPrasath You should stop pushing people into giving you advice. Be patient. And make an effort to solve things yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `AS tbltemp` to alias a table in Oracle. The `AS` keyword can only used to alias columns, not tables. You can either remove the `AS` keyword, or in this case since you don't refer to the alias, remove the whole `AS tbltemp` part. [Here's an SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f4562/2).

It looks like the parser initially tries to interpret `AS` *as the alias name*, and then doesn't know what the `tbltemp` is supposed to mean.

ZZa's approach is better anyway, but you could also use anayltic functions to avoid hitting the tables multiple times:

```
select hospitalid, hname, htype from (
  select hospitalid, hname, htype, doc_count,
    rank() over (order by doc_count desc) as rn
  from (
    select h.hospitalid, h.hname, h.htype,
        count(d.doctorid) as doc_count
    from hospital h
    join doctor d on d.hospitalid = h.hospitalid
    group by h.hospitalid, h.hname, h.htype
  )
)
where rn = 1;
```

Another [SQL Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f4562/5). The innermost `select` does the counting, the next level ranks the grouped results in descending order of the number of doctors at each hospital, and the outermost restricts that to the highest-ranked.

Either way, if there's a tie - two hospitals with the same number of doctors - you'll get multiple rows back. If that's not what you want you'd need to decide how to break the tie.

Answer (score 1):

Try this but not tested

```
select * from hospital where hospitalid =
 (select hospitalid from doctor group by hospitalid having count ( doctorid ) =
  (select max ( doctoramt ) from
      (select count (doctorid) as doctoramt from doctor group by hospitalid) as tbltemp)));
```

Comment: Same missing right paranthesis error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT h.hospitalid, h.hname, h.htype 
FROM hospital h, doctor d
WHERE h.hospitalid = d.hospitalid
GROUP BY h.hospitalid, h.hname, h.htype 
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT MAX(a) from (SELECT COUNT(*) a from doctor group by hospitalid));
```