# SQL - updating Oracle 10g database from a complex query

Tags: sql, oracle

trying to update a single column based on criteria.  The rows that need to be updated are returned by the query

```
SELECT 
it.objectid,
it.versionnumber,
it.itemnumber "Item Number", 
it.itemtype,
itcovprem.basisofsettlement,
itcovprem.coverage "Coverage"
FROM 
itemcoveragesandpremiums itcovprem,
items it,
policies pl
WHERE 
pl.objectid = it.parentobjectid AND 
pl.policytype in ('H','F') AND
it.objectid = itcovprem.itemobjectid AND
it.itemtype in ('SHOA','SHOB','SHOC','SHOD','SHOK','SHOL') and
it.versionnumber = itcovprem.itemversionnumber AND
((itcovprem.coverage like ('A - Dwg Bldg%')) or
(itcovprem.coverage like ('#42 - Repl Cost Plus%')) or
(itcovprem.coverage like ('#42 - Limited GRC%'))) and
it.effectivedate >= TO_DATE('01-JAN-2006', 'DD-MON-YYYY') and
exists (select * from itemcoveragesandpremiums icp where icp.itemobjectid = it.objectid and icp.itemversionnumber = it.versionnumber and icp.coverage like ('#42%')) and
itcovprem.basisofsettlement not in ('LGRC')
```

I've tried a few options to convert this to an update query, but no joy.

I get Error - line 3 - SQL command not properly ended when using

```
update itemcoveragesandpremiums
set basisofsettlement = 'LGRC'
from itemcoveragesandpremiums as itcovprem
inner join items as it
on it.objectid = itcovprem.itemobjectid and it.versionnumber = itcovprem.itemversionnumber
inner join policies as pl
on pl.objectid = it.parentobjectid 
where [cut, rest of query was below]
```

I get Error - line 6 - missing right parenthesis when trying use an inline query

```
update
(
SELECT 
itcovprem.basisofsettlement as OLD
FROM 
itemcoveragesandpremiums as itcovprem inner join items as it on it.objectid = itcovprem.itemobjectid and it.versionnumber = itcovprem.itemversionnumber inner join policies AS pl on pl.objectid = it.parentobjectid 
WHERE [query snipped]
) t
set t.old = 'LGRC'
```

Seems that SQL*Plus just wants to stop looking at the update before it gets to the meat of my select query.  I'm not sure if I'm formatting it incorrectly or going at it from the wrong direction.  Any advice?

Comment: Unless something changed since my "Oracle days", Oracle does not support JOIN in UPDATE statements.

Comment: The last one is because you can't use `as` to alias a table name; it's only valid to alias column names. Here the parser sees `as` as the alias, and then doesn't know what to do with `itcovprem`. But an inline view with joins is unlikely to be updateable anyway.

Comment: You might want to check this older post and see if any of the approaches work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first attempt, the error at line 3 is because `update` doesn't support a `from` or `join` clause. In your second attempt the immediate error at line 6 is because you're trying to alias a table with `as itcovprem`; but [you can only use `as` for column aliases, not for table aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16580995/266304). (The first attempt is trying to do that too, but it isn't getting as far as encountering that problem). But you can't generally update an inline-view with joins anyway, so it would still error with that - something like an ORA-01779.

You would need to do something like:

```
update itemcoveragesandpremiums
set basisofsettlement = 'LGRC'
where (itemobjectid, itemversionnumber, basisofsettlement, coverage) in (
  select it.objectid,
    it.versionnumber,
    itcovprem.basisofsettlement,
    itcovprem.coverage
  from ...
)
```

Assuming that `itemobjectid, itemversionnumber, basisofsettlement, coverage` identifies a row sufficiently such that you don't risk updating anything you shouldn't. It might be safer to add a `rowid` to the select and use that for the update instead to avoid ambiguity:

```
update itemcoveragesandpremiums
set basisofsettlement = 'LGRC'
where rowid in (
  select itcovprem.rowid as target_rowid
  from ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I will dig into this one shortly.  Much appreciated!